# Can you modify NextJS mount element or add classes to __next div?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, jsx, tailwind-css

Long story short is I'm working on a project where I want to have the content "fill" the vertical space below the static header. I've done this in React with tailwind like this:

```
<body class="flex flex-col h-screen text-gray-600 work-sans leading-normal text-base tracking-normal">
    <header class="flex h-18 bg-white shadow-md">
        {/* header menu options */}
    </header>
    <div class="flex flex-1 h-full bg-gray-200 p-6">
        {/* page content */}
    </div>
```

But with NextJS it seems to put the mounting div (i.e. `<div id="__next">`) between the body and the wrest of the content. If I modify the CSS to give `#__next { height: %100 }` but that makes the fill not work correctly, it overflows. So it looks like this:

```
<body class="flex flex-col h-screen text-gray-600 work-sans leading-normal text-base tracking-normal">
    <div id="__next">
        <header class="flex h-18 bg-white shadow-md">
            {/* header menu options */}
        </header>
        <div class="flex flex-1 h-full bg-gray-200 p-6">
            {/* page content */}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here are screenshots to visually see why the extra div is causing problems: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZloH.jpg

The two possible options to solve this problem that theoretically might work are add classes to the `#__next` div or mount to body instead of the `#__next` div. Does anyone know how to achieve either of those?

Edit: Yes, I think I could change the layout to a fixed header and padding on top of the content element and that'd sidestep the problem and that may end up being the workaround I need but I'm still interested in knowing if either of the solutions I've mentioned are possible because if they aren't that's a technical limitation of NextJS that doesn't get much attention.

Comment: set __next height 100% and box-sizing: border-box; padding and margin on 0

Comment: and body, html height 100%

Comment: @Robert The result is the same as the overflow picture I posted to imgur

Comment: your header is fixed height. h-18, so just calc(100% - 18px) should be fine, or put this layer as absolute top 0 and min-height 100% should work as well. (but in second case you have to change zindex of header)

Comment: or better. if header is always on top just make it fixed mean position: fixed and top: 0. this will remove it from __nav and height of 100 % will treated as 100% of page not plus height of header

Comment: I've never seen calc(100% - 18px). I'll have to give it a try. That's a good point, I could change the way I put the navigation header at the top but then I'd have to compensate by adding a top padding to the content space. Thanks for your suggestions! I'll report back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing classes from the body and applying them to the `#__next` container div:

I used the approach in this [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-tailwindcss) for using tailwind with Next.js.

Then I edited `styles/index.css`

```
@tailwind base;

/* Write your own custom base styles here */
/* #__next {
  height: 100%;
} */

/* Start purging... */
@tailwind components;
/* Stop purging. */

html,
body {
  @apply bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900;
}

#__next {
  @apply flex flex-col h-screen text-gray-600 leading-normal text-base tracking-normal;
}

/* Write your own custom component styles here */
.btn-blue {
  @apply px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white bg-blue-500 rounded;
}

/* Start purging... */
@tailwind utilities;
/* Stop purging. */

/* Your own custom utilities */
```

As you said, the point is to add the classes to `#__next` instead of the `body`.

As you can see in the comments, it's important where to add the `@apply` instruction.

The important lines are:

```
#__next {
  @apply flex flex-col h-screen text-gray-600 leading-normal text-base tracking-normal;
}
```

As you've asked in your question title, this is one way to add tailwind styles to the `#__next` container div.

The other solution is to set the classes after the component or page is loaded using the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook or the `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("#__next").className =
      "flex flex-col h-screen text-gray-600 leading-normal text-base tracking-normal";
  }, []);
```

If you take a look at the Next.js documentation about [Custom document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) you can see that the `Main` component and `NextScript` are the internals of Next.js and are required for the page to be properly rendered, and you can not change Next.js internals, so I think the solutions mentioned above are the best ways to **add classes to the #__next container div.**

Comment: I think this may be the closest thing to actually solving the problem but not exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to Nextjs and it seems like it arbitrarily adds the #__next div to mount the Nextjs to and it doesn't seem configurable at all. I was hoping to get some insight into the inner workings of Nextjs or possibly a possible improvement that could be made.

Comment: As you've mentioned n your question title: " or add classes to __next div? " these are the ways you can achieve your goal.

Comment: While it doesn't settle my creative/intellectual query about Nextjs, this solved my problem so I'm going to give you the reward.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to inject elements between or replace NextJS' technical root element (`#__next`). Just stretch all parent elements of your app's root element to take all the screen height with `100vh` (vh is "vertical height", a unit which is 1% of the viewport height).

```css
html, body, #__next, #app {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Your HTML might look like this:

```html
<html>
<head><!-- head content --></head>
<body>
  <div id="__next">
    <div id="app"><!-- this is your app's top element --></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change your `html` or `body` tags by creating a custom document in `./pages/_document.js`

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body className="custom-class-name">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default CustomDocument
```

Take into account that these tags DO need to be included in your file: `<Html>`, `<Head />`, `<Main />` and `<NextScript />`.

Here's the [full documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

In your case, that element with the __next id  is just what the  element renders, and it's  required for the main app to be mounted on. So you can't remove it or edit it. I think you can  add some css in _document.js that targets #__next, using the @apply directive from tailwind might be the way to go instead of editing the HTML of the  element (since it doesn't seem to be possible)

Comment: I have a custom document like outlined here and in the documentation but Nextjs still inserts a div with the id __next between body and the page content.

Comment: I see. That element with the __next id  is just what the <Main /> element renders, and it's  required for the main app to be mounted on. So you can't remove it or edit it. I think you can  add some css in _document.js that targets #__next, using the @apply directive from tailwind might be the way to go instead of editing the HTML of the <Main /> element (since it doesn't seem to be possible)

Comment: That's unfortunate. I almost think that it'd be better to either have the mount point configurable or mount to body rather than an arbitrary div that is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I found updating the `styles/globals.css` to be the easiest way to achieve this.

```
/*
  Extend the top most enclosing elements to entire height of the screen 
  to allow for the background image to fill the entire screen
*/
html,
body,
#__next {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Note that that `global.css` has to be imported into `_app.tsx`